# tkinter Label Isn't showing

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm following a well reviewed python book called "Python programming" and have followed the book to the letter, until in the middle of programming I wanted to test out my label so I tried. Code runs fine but label didn't appear. Please help me. Code is down below.

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import *

class Safe(Frame):
    """ PS """
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initalize the frame """
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """ Create button , text, and entry widgets """
        # Create instuction label
        self.inst_label = Label(self, text = "Welcome")
        self.inst_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

#main
root = Tk()
root.title("Password Safe")
root.geometry("500x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks that looks a lot better

Comment: can anybody answer me

Comment: You never create an instance of `Safe`.

Comment: `NameError: name 'Application' is not defined` will be raised if you try to make an instance of `Safe`, I assume because your book uses `Application` as the class name instead of `Safe`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to instantiate the class. Root is just an empty window.

```
mywindow = Safe()
mywindow.title("Password Safe")
mywindow.mainloop()
```

- `self.create_widgets()` will add the widgets to the frame.
- `self.inst_label.grid()` will tell Tk how to pack the label.

So, you should be good to go from there.

Comment: It might be good to also note that he should be saying `super(Safe, ...)` instead of `super(Application, ...)`.

Comment: thanks everyone for answers i'm really grateful for everything.